# Symfony change dropdown values with query builder after form submit

Tags: forms, symfony, events, query-builder, event-listener

I'd like to filter a dropdown list depending on the choices I made in 4 previous dropdowns. My form type looks like that:

```
class DocumentDeactivationType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {

    $builder
    ->add('type', 'choice', array('choices' => array(
        'document_types.contract' => 1,
        'document_types.general'=>2,
        'document_types.goodwill_policy'=>3,
        'document_types.pricesheet'=>4,
        'document_types.yq_update'=>5,
        'document_types.contract_addendum'=>6),
        'choices_as_values' => true, 'label' => 'label.types',
        'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'label.type', 'required' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'Documents'))

    -> add('status', 'entity', array(
      'class' => 'DocumentBundle:Status', 'property' => 'name',
      'choice_label' => 'translationkey', 'label' => 'Status',
      'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'required' => false,
      'translation_domain' => 'Documents',
      'choice_translation_domain' => 'Documents',))


    ->add('airlines', 'entity', array(
      'class' => 'AppBundle:Airline', 'property' => 'id',
      'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er){
       return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
       ->addOrderBy('a.id', 'ASC');
       },
      'choice_value' => 'id',
      'choice_label' => 'id', 'label' => 'label.airlines',
      'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'required' => false,
      'translation_domain' => 'Documents'))

    ->add('markets', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Market', 'property' => 'id',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er){
         return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
         ->addOrderBy('m.id', 'ASC');
         },
        'choice_value' => 'id',
        'choice_label' => 'id', 'label' => 'label.markets',
        'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'required' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'Documents'))

    ->add('documentlist', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'DocumentBundle:Document',
        'property' => 'name',
        'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'label.document_list',
        'empty_value' => "Select document",
        'required' => false,
        'mapped' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'Documents'));

  $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder)
      {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        $markets = $data['markets'];
        $status = $data['status'];
        $type = $data['type'];
        $airlines = $data['airlines'];
    $builder
    ->add('documentlist', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'DocumentBundle:Document',
        'property' => 'name',
        'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'label.document_list',
        'empty_value' => "Select document",
        'required' => false,
        'mapped' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'Documents',

        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($markets, $status, $type, $airlines){
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->where('e.markets IN (:markets)')
        ->andWhere('e.status IN (:status)')
        ->andWhere('e.airlines IN (:airlines)')
        ->andWhere('e.products IN (:products)')
        ->setParameter('markets', $markets)
        ->setParameter('status', $status)
        ->setParameter('airlines', $airlines)
        ->setParameter('type', $type);
      },
      ));
  });
}
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'document_deactivation';

    }
  }
```

I'm not sure whether it's obvious: the 'documentlist' dropdown is already there with all the values from the document entity and what I try to achieve through the PRE_SUBMIT EventListener is kind of updating its values dependent on the choices from the 4 other dropdowns.
There is an 'Apply' button for the 4 dropdowns so I shouldn't need an ajax request but Post/PreSubmit events I guess?
My problems:

1. When selecting some values from the "filter" dropdowns but e.g. leaving out the 'markets', I get the error "Undefined index for markets" which is probably because of the line $markets = $data['markets'] --> so what I want here is being able to filter only on some of the types and not being forced to select all of them.
2. Updating the documentlist dropdown isn't working at all. I don't even think, the query builder is doing anything. But I'm not sure whether that has something to do with my FormEvent or maybe the way I add the dropdown to the form.

how everything is rendered in my twig file:

```
    {% block filterContent %}
  {{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_row(form.type) }}
  {{ form_row(form.status) }}
  {{ form_row(form.markets)}}
  {{ form_row(form.airlines)}}
    <input type="submit" class="btn-primary btn btn-xs" value="Apply Filter" />

  <br clear="all" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{{ form_label(form.documentlist) }}
{{ form_widget(form.documentlist) }}
{{ form_end(form) }} </br>

<div class="row">
  {% include 'AppBundle::HelpSubmitButton.html.twig' with { 'buttonName': 'label.submit'|trans } %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: 2) I believe you will need to update the list via AJAX as  `PRE_SUBMIT` will happen just before the `submit` action so it will use all values in `documentlist`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add an if statement around $market

```
if (isset($data['markets'])) {$markets = $data['markets'];}
```

And

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($markets, $status, $type, $airlines) {
    $query =  $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->where('e.status IN (:status)')
    ->andWhere('e.airlines IN (:airlines)')
    ->andWhere('e.products IN (:products)')
    ->setParameter('markets', $markets)
    ->setParameter('status', $status)
    ->setParameter('airlines', $airlines)
    ->setParameter('type', $type);
  };

   if (isset($data['markets'])) {
     $query->andWhere('e.markets IN (:markets)')
   }
```

2) I believe you will need to update the list via AJAX as  `PRE_SUBMIT` will happen just before the `submit` action so it will use all values in `documentlist`.

Comment: thank you @user742736, I tried setting up an ajax function to do as you said but the data I send to my controller to handle the request is empty. could you provide an example of how it works?